# Navigation bar without <ul>

Tags: html, css, semantics

I'm quite new to html/css/js so apologise in advance if this is a newbie question.
Every time I see a navigation bar people tend to use ul/li. However I think you can achieve the exact same result just by using and formatting the 'a' tags thus reducing the html code, like the example below:

html:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="top-nav">
      <a href="#about">About me</a>
      <a href="#education">Education</a>
      <a href="#work">Work</a>
      <a href="#interests">Interests &#38; Hobbies</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

css:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

/* Header section.*/
header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

/* Navigation */
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-nav a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: white;
}

.top-nav a:hover {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with doing this in terms of semantics, etc? If so, why and what are the advantages of using the ul/li tags?

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc7oqtg9/1/) for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Using `ul > li` implies a semantic bond between the elements of the list, which your example does not have. It's the sole reason why most navigation blocks are made out of lists.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that your question is about semantics.

There is no explicit precision about the form of the content of the navigation element `<nav>` (whether it use `<li> <ol>` or just `<a>`).

If you have a peek at [the nav element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) you can see how it relates to the accessibility [navigation role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Navigation_Role).
Likewise, you can look at [the ul element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) and how it related to the accessibility [list role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/List_role).

So the semantic difference would be that a series of `<a>` is more related to plain text entries that link somewhere. When encapsulated in a `<ul>` it takes the meaning of a `list of links`. The latter is probably more explicit to define the concept of a navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a dropdown below every item the you will need to have ul tags to achieve that result. You just cannot simply add a dropdown menu by using anchor a tags thats why you will see most of the people using ul tags followed by li tags inside to make the dropdown menu. If you just want to show the items on your navbar and dont want to have a dropdown then this approach may be okay..:)